# Using "standard" literature in local language instead of English literature

Tags: computer-science, language, literature

I'm currently working on a paper where I want to compare UML with a "leaner" approach of modelling software architecture. UML already has some coverage by writers (besides the open specification), and therefore some books that can be considered as "standard literature", e.g. UML Distilled or The Unified Modeling Language User Guide. In Germany, there is also a German UML-related book that can be considered standard literature (UML 2 glasklar).
I'm now struggling a bit - I'm writing the paper in English, however currently it's easier for me to get access to the German literature (digital access to German books vs. physical English books in the library, which is closed due to COVID-19 lock-down).

Can I use the German book as reference and work with it, without impact to "credibility"? Or should I wait and try to get my grip on the English standard literature, as the German one will not be considered a good reference?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there is anything deficient in the German literature on UML. Citing all German works in a paper written in English on a CS topic is a bit odd, though, unless the primary audience is actually German readers.

Comment: My thought was not really about the quality of the book - as far as I can tell, the book itself is solid and well-written. It's more about the second part you mentioned, how awkward or odd would it be to cite German literature, whilst English literature is available, and how this could impact credibility of the work. _Edit:_ Didn't know `Enter` would directly save my comment :-X Thanks!